# libssh in c++, avoid manually set a delay for reading data after send command

Tags: c++, ssh

One of my machine device need to communicate using SSH protocol, so I am using a SSH library (c++) for my project. Please refer to this link : https://www.libssh.org/

Below is part of my code:

```
ssh_channel_write(m_channel,cmd.c_str(),cmd.length());
Sleep(30);
char buffer[256];
m_nbytes = ssh_channel_read(m_channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

Everytime when I want to trace some data from the device, I will send a command, then wait for awhile (here I put Sleep(30)), and finally read the data.

My problem is, actually I don't know how much time should I put, I just put Sleep(30) and it seem works well for me, if I put too little time, it will not function well.

So, do you know any method that allow my code to wait until it is ready to read after I send command ? So I don't have to put a Sleep(30).
[By using same library]

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "it will not function well", what do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate? Are you using non-blocking communication?

Comment: I dint set anything related to blocking, so it should be by default. "Not function well" means, let said I send "command A" and I expect to receive "result A", but since my wait time is too short, I send command A, then command B, my "result A" may receive during I send command B. In the ssh_channel_read function